How to know heap overflow point?
I'm attempting to write a program that determines all palindrome within a given range.  My program calls a function (number of digits) that returns the size of an integer (ie. 400 would be 3 as it has 3 digits), then (another - Splitis) returns a numbers place (ie. for 400, 3 would return 4 as that's the third digit.  The program then stores the independant values on a pointer array.  For example, (100 would be stored as 1,0,0).  As the size of each element changes, you would have to use a double pointer, one for the total numbers, then one for each element based upon the size of the number.  For some strange reason, I get a segmentation fault at when my array exceeds roughly 8000 pointers.  Because it always fails at that point like clockwork and it seems to work better when I make malloc smaller, I'm assuming I'm overflowing the heap somehow.  Anways, I'm trying to figure out why I keep getting a segfault?  The code is below.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "external file location"

int main(void)
{
double testsize=0;
int count=0;
int **currentarray;
int *innerarray=NULL;
size_t sizeofarray=9000;
currentarray=(int **)malloc(sizeof(int)*sizeofarray);
for(int A=0; A<sizeofarray; A++)
{
    size_t b=numberofdigits(&A);
    *(currentarray+A)=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*b*1);
    if(currentarray==NULL)
    {
    perror("malloc failed");
    }
    int c=0;
    for(c=b; c>=1; c--)
    {
    *(*(currentarray+A)+c)=SplitIs(A, c);       
    }
    if((*(*(currentarray+A)+1)==*(*(currentarray+A)+b)) && (b>1))
    {
    fprintf(stdout, "%d)", count++);
        for(int c=b; c>=1; c--)
        {
        fprintf(stdout, "%d", *(*(currentarray+A)+c));
        }
    putchar('\n');
    }
}
for(int i=0;i<sizeofarray; i++)
{
//free((currentarray+i)); //I haven't figured out how to free it yet as the pointer is contained in the above block.  Commented out for now.  A future question.
}
}


Your second malloc line has malloc(sizeof(int)*b*1);.  I'm pretty sure you want that to be +1, not *1, since you start your array counting at 1, not at 0.

Your pointer manipulation would be a lot clearer if you just used array notation.  currentarray[A][1] is a lot easier to read than *(*(currentarray+A)+1).  However, your code works for me.

You're sure that numberofdigits is supposed to take a POINTER to int?  It doesn't make much sense.  It doesn't need a pointer.

And your first malloc should be doing sizeof(int*), not sizeof(int).  And finally, your free should be free(*(currentarray+i));.  You need to free the contents, not the value.

And as a FINAL comment, this only checks whether the first and last digits are the same.  It doesn't check for palindromes.  That would not be a hard function to add, of course.

You're correct about that function not needing to use a pointer.  I'm a newbie to C and was trying to speed things up by using a pointer; however, I doubt an integer is all that slow anyways.

"Speed things up"?? How?  Pointers are larger than integers, and when you pass a pointer, the function has to take the unnecessary extra step of dereferencing the pointer.  Do not fall into the "micro-optimizing" trap.  Do what makes sense, then worry about speed.

I have fixed up the issues I mentioned above, and your code seems to work without error.  Note that I have supplied versions of numberofdigits and SplitIs, since you didn't supply them.
You check for failure on the second malloc, but not the first.
This would be a lot more reliable in C++.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int numberofdigits( int * x )
{
    int c = 1;
    int d = 0;
    while( *x > c )
    {
        d += 1;
        c *= 10;
    }
    return d;
}

int SplitIs( int a, int c )
{
    while( --c )
        a /= 10;
    return a % 10;
}

int main(void)
{
    int count=0;
    int **currentarray;
    int *innerarray=NULL;
    size_t sizeofarray=9000;
    currentarray=(int **)malloc(sizeof(int*)*sizeofarray);
    for(int A=0; A<sizeofarray; A++)
    {
        int b=numberofdigits(&A);
        currentarray[A]=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*b+1);
        if(!currentarray)
        {
            perror("malloc failed");
        }
        int c=0;
        for(c=b; c>=1; c--)
        {
            currentarray[A][c]=SplitIs(A, c);       
        }
        if((currentarray[A][1]==currentarray[A][b]) && (b>1))
        {
            fprintf(stdout, "%d)", count++);
            for(int c=b; c>=1; c--)
            {
                fprintf(stdout, "%d", currentarray[A][c]);
            }
            putchar('\n');
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<sizeofarray; i++)
    {
        free(currentarray[i]);
    }
    free(currentarray);
}


Thank you, the lack of (* to int) in "currentarray=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*sizeofarray);" was in fact causing the system to run out of memory/crash.  The syntax for malloc and it's typecasts is extremely tricky.  I have a book i'm trying to work through on just pointers.   From what I gather, you work from the lowest level out?  So the first malloc is the lowest int, and the second one is the higher version?

I'm not sure what you mean.  The first malloc is allocating room for 9000 pointers.  The second malloc allocates an array for each number in the loop, one per slot in the first array.
